# TypeError: doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-sheets-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdR7V.png)not able to access google sheets via Service access authorization even after requiring all the credential files. It says doc.ServiceAccountAuth is not a function.

I am trying to transfer my mongo db data to google spreadsheets using Nodejs but while giving access to google sheets it fails.

Comment: please donot post images. Instead post the code itself.

Comment: Hey @Hoax, been able to resolve this? Same error here.

Answer (score 5):

The new way of working of authenticating the `GoogleSpreadsheet` package is by instantiating the auth separately like:

```js
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';

const serviceAccountAuth = new JWT({
    email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    ],
});

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('<the sheet ID from the url>', serviceAccountAuth);
```

It uses the official `google-auth-library` package to do that, and just injects the authentication to the `GoogleSpreadsheet` constructor, which them wires up everything inside.

Your code tries to use `doc.useServiceAccountAuth()`, which looks to be a deprecated way of doing that, also because this function doesn't even exist in the package anymore.